# For $n\geq 3$ there exist $x,y\in S_n$ such that $x$ and $y$ have order $2$ and $xy$ has order $n$.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Assume that $n\geq 3$. Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group with $n!$ elements. Prove that there exists $x$ and $y$ in $S_n$ such that $x$ and $y$ have order $2$ and $xy$ has order $n$.

For $n=3$, it is easy to see that $x=(1, 2)$ and $y=(1, 3)$ works. How to prove it for the general case?

Comment: Do a few more specific cases, such as $n=4$ and $n=5$ -- that should give you an idea of how this works in general.

Answer (score 3):

Take $x$ to be the permutation $i\mapsto n+1-i$, and $z$ to be the forward rotation $i\mapsto i+1$ if $i<n$ and $i\mapsto 1$ if $i=n$. Then clearly $x^2=1$, and $y=xz=z^{-1}x$ has order 2.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $D_n \leq S_n$ and $D_n$ has the property that you have described.Now  write the terms of $D_n$ in permutation notation.

Take $$f= \prod_{i=2}^{\frac{[n+1]}{2}} (i, n+2-i)$$ and $$g=\prod_{i=1}^{\frac{[n]}{2}} (i, n+1-i)$$ then $$fg=(1,2,...,n)$$