# Let $n\geq 3$. Find all permutations $\alpha ,\beta \in S_n$ both with order 2 such that $\alpha \beta$ has order $n$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Here is my attempt, followed by the questions I have.

Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have order two, they must be products of disjoint 2-cycles. This is one possible permutation:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \alpha =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\cdots \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n-1 & n \\
\end{array}
\right) & n \text{ is } \text{even} \\
 \beta =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)\cdots \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n-2 & n-1 \\
\end{array}
\right) &   \\
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \alpha =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\cdots \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n-2 & n-1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & n \text{ is } \text{odd} \\
 \beta =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)\cdots \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n-1 & n \\
\end{array}
\right) &   \\
\end{array}$$

Other permutations:

For any set of distinct numbers $S=\left\{a_1,a_2,\cdots ,a_m\right\}$ with $\text{LCM}(S)=n$, create a list where $a_i$ repeats $k_i$
times and $\sum _ik_ia_i=n$. Then create $\sum _i k_i$ disjoint subsets of $\{1,2,3,\cdots ,n\}$ (with $k_i$ of the $\sum _i k_i$ subsets having $a_i$ elements).

For each subset, create permutations by the above method (depending on $a_i$ being odd or even) and then take products of the resulting permutations. This also gives $\alpha \beta$ with order $n$ (easy to prove).

For example, with $n=30$, the list $S=\{5,3,2,1\}$ with $k_1=1,k_2=2,k_3=1,k_4=17$ gives:

$\alpha =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\circ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 6 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right)\circ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 9 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right)\circ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 12 & 13 \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
\beta =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)\circ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 7 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right)\circ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 10 & 11 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

The non-trivial subsets here are $\{1,2,3,4,5\},\{6,7,8\},\{9,10,11\},\{12,13\}$.

Furthermore, for any given list $S$ with repetitions $(k_i)$, rearranging and substituting the numbers will give this many permutations:
$$\frac{n!}{\prod _ik_i!a_i^{k_i}}$$

Questions: do these permutations include every possibility? How to show that these include everything?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821013/existence-of-elements-of-order-2-in-s-n-whose-product-has-order-n?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more examples, or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395015/for-n-geq-3-there-exist-x-y-in-s-n-such-that-x-and-y-have-order-2-and?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think those examples already fit into ones covered here.

Comment: How would the two elements of order two, namely $sr$ and $sr^2$ in this post, fit here?

Comment: For example for $n=5$ there can be $s=(25)(34)$ and $r=(12345)$. This gives $sr$ and $sr^2$ in the form described above for odd $n$.